# is there any difference between process.exitcode and process.exit() in node?

Tags: node.js, process, exit

What is the difference between process.exitcode and process.exit() ?
If I use process.exitode = 1 and process.exit(1) does this create any difference or its just a alternate way to do ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a difference.

- [`process.exitCode`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processexitcode_1) only sets the exit code that will be used when the process eventually exits. It does NOT tell the process to exit, only what code to use when it does.
- [`process.exit([code])`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processexitcode) will terminate the process with the given exit code, or with the value of `process.exitCode` if it has been set, or with the exit code 0 (success) by default.

The difference is that `exit` will exit as quickly as possible (after all 'exit' event listeners are called), even if there are pending async operations, including I/O operations. This can lead to surprising behaviour!

If you don't need to exit as soon as possible or if your code has a lot of async operations, it's safer to use `exitCode` and let the process exit gracefully when all operations have completed.

Answer (score 2):

`process.exitcode = 1` doesn't do anything consequential. Be careful of capitalisation.

From [docs on `process.exitCode`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exitcode):

> A number which will be the process exit code, when the process either exits gracefully, or is exited via process.exit() without specifying a code.

Thus,

```
process.exitCode = 1;
// ...
process.exit();
```

is equivalent to

```
process.exit(1);
```

Notably,

```
process.exitCode = 1;
process.exitCode = 2;
process.exit();
```

is not equivalent to

```
process.exit(1);
process.exit(2);
```

Also,

```
process.exitCode = 1;
console.log("bye");
process.exit();
```

is not equivalent to

```
process.exit(1);
console.log("bye");
```

Comment: it means if i do process.exitCode = 1, it will works with async task while the process.exit(1) don't ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "it will works". `process.exitCode = 1` doesn't exit. They both _work_, but they do different things.

Comment: If I do 
`process.exit(1);
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("bye");
}, 2000);`
It exit the process without printing bye but if i change to `process.exitCode = 1` it exit process by printing bye.

Comment: Yes, because `process.exitCode = 1` _doesn't exit_. It has nothing to do with asynchronicity. To exit, you need to either call `process.exit`, or you need to run out of script. Please read the quote again; it says nothing about exiting. Assignment to `process.exitCode` does not exit. No exiting is happening when you execute `process.exitCode = 1`.

Comment: I think process.exitCode = 1 will exit. As its mentioned in node JS documentation.

- the process.exitCode allow the process to exit naturally by avoiding scheduling any additional work for the event loop

Comment: So, despite me explaining how it doesn't exit, quoting (and linking to) the documentation that doesn't say it exits (but sets the exit code to be used _when and if_ an exit happens without the code being explicitly specified), your experiments that _prove_ it doesn't exit, you still think it exits. Check. I don't think there's anything for me left to say.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203952/discussion-between-vipin-and-amadan).

Comment: You misunderstood what the documentation is saying. Reading the context around that quote, it says that it is better to set the exitCode _and then allow the program to exit naturally_ (by either running out of things to do, or by throwing an exception that will cut through the remaining code) than using `process.exit`, because `process.exit` is abrupt and doesn't allow for things to clean up nicely. Again, `process.exitCode = 1` does not exit any more than `let x = 3` does; it is a set-up step for the case when the program does end — whether naturally, or by `process.exit` with no arguments.